# Query to list which string how many occured in a table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array of strings and a table with text type column. I want to list which string how many occured in specified column of any row in table. Is there a way to do this with one query?

```
Example;
$strings = array('test', 'sth');

Table;
id | someTextColumn
-------------------
1  | abc tests
2  | sthab
3  | teststh
4  | abcd
5  | sth

Expected result;
str  | occurences
-----------------
test | 2
sth  | 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a series of `like` statements.

Here is an example:

```
select totest.str, count(t.id)
from (select 'test' as str union all
      select 'sth'
     ) totest left outer join
     t
     on t.someTextColumn like concat('%', totest.str, '%')
group by totest.str
```

This is not going to be particularly fast if your tables are large.  If you have largish tables, you might want to consider full-text indexing.

Comment: This is working except zero occurences. Is there a way to add it too?

Comment: @m_poorUser . . . Yes, you need an outer join for that (which also requires changing the `count(*)` to `count(id)`.

Comment: `count(totest.id)` should be `count(t.id)`. It works, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the table size isn't too large and the column is properly indexed:

```
SELECT 'test', COUNT(id)
FROM tableName
WHERE someTextColumn LIKE '%test%'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'sth', COUNT(id)
FROM tableName
WHERE someTextColumn LIKE '%sth%'
```

Comment: Table will approximately have 100 rows but strings may be a lot more than that. This is a query will work once a week. So if there is not a better way to do it, I can use this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "select someTextColumn, count(id) from tableName where "
for($i=0; $i < count($Strings); $i++)
{
   if($i != 0)
   $query .= " OR ";
   $query .= "someTextColumn =" . $string[$i];
}
$query .= " group by someTextColumn";

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Try this I hope this will solve ur problem!!

Comment: I need to know which string how many times occured and there can be two string in same cell, so this is not working for me.

Comment: Ok. Now I got better understanding of your question I will try to right another query for that requirement.

Comment: Did you try this query? is it giving count of absolute occurrence of a string of array in your table.

Comment: I need them seperatly. Check out my expected result. Also plus signs in your code should be dots, and $value should be $Strings[$i], and there is a misspelled "from" keyword in query. These can be confusing for someone who doesn't know php much, so please edit.